# The app is working fine on connected devices but its showing error when i try to build its apk

Tags: java, android, android-studio

There is no error when I try to run it on connected devices or on emulator but, when I try to build its apk file, it's generating this error. Please help me out if you find any clue of mistake here. Thanks

The error is:

> Error:Execution failed for task 
>     ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
>          com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex`

The build.gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.ihtesham.demoapp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}
buildTypes {

    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

}

}

dependencies {

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'



androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'   //1.0.1
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
core:3.0.1'

//Adding libraries


implementation 'com.github.glomadrian:MaterialAnimatedSwitch:1.1@aar'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.3'
implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.2'
implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'   // 26.1.0
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'  //11.8.0
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'  //11.4.2
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'//11.8.0
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The project's build.gradle is:

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
        maven{
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    maven{
        url 'https://dl.bintray.com/glomadrian/maven'
    }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: everything here seems fine. please show the project's build.gradle which you are using whats the version of gems class path

Comment: I have edited my post please check it out. Thanks

Comment: I just answered a solution try that if that does not work then comment under it so I could get you another fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

Or do it

```
multiDexEnabled false
```

from your project's build.gradle because the exception you are facing is telling something about not being able to compile the dex code.

after removing that line or doing it false try to CLEAN and then ->REBUILD and go for buildapk.

if you are going for releasing your apk then you have to do some more amends in your application's build.gradle like this

```
buildTypes {

release {
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
    'proguard-rules.pro'
    multiDexEnabled false
}
```

in your program-rules pro file you have to put these lines too its good practice well to me actually

```
-keep class * {
public private *;
}
```

if that does not work! keep the multidexEnabled true and add this in your project dependencies

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
```

Comment: Thanks for effort :) I did  "multiDexEnable false" and after that i have clean the project and then rebuild it. But after rebuilding the project its showing me the same error which i have told you about.

Comment: I did the changes you have said and clean the project and rebuild it but still getting the same error.

Comment: Thanks buddy your answer just save my life :D .. dependency method worked thanks again :)

Comment: glad it helped @QaziIhtesham